# AWS Cognito error "attempted to write unauthorized attribute" but I have added the attribute to the pool

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to add a custom attribute to my cognito users for hasSubscription, and add/update it during signup and login

```
        var hasSubscriptionAttribute = new AttributeType
        {
            Name = "custom:hasSubscription",
            Value = "0"
        };
        request.UserAttributes.Add(hasSubscriptionAttribute);
```

I have already added the attribute in cognito via the console 
[image]
[image]

Yet, I still always get the error

> A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your console you declared your custom attribute "twice" as custom.
your namefield is `custom:hasSubscription`
but it has to be only `hasSubscription`.
Cognito knows, that this field is a custom attribute by default.

Your request stays the same.

For example: With your **current declaration** of your custom attribute your request has to be

```
var hasSubscriptionAttribute = new AttributeType
    {
        Name = "custom:custom:hasSubscription",
        Value = "0"
    };
    request.UserAttributes.Add(hasSubscriptionAttribute);
```

I made this mistake too and it drove me crazy :)

Comment: Hmm that doesn’t make sense. I only wrote “hasSubscription” and it automatically prefixed with “custom:”, there is an other custom attribute that’s setup in the same manner which works without issue, same naming scheme and everything.

Comment: Yeah, tried it as you suggested with `Name = "custom:custom:hasSubscription"`, same error :( any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out thanks to https://medium.com/graymatrix/using-custom-attributes-in-amazon-cognito-user-pool-288cd3128bae

I didn't set the read/write permission on the new attribute, which is set at App Clients -> Show More -> Set attribute read and write permissions

[image]